# Typescript Type Annotations throws 'Unexpected token ":"'

Tags: node.js, typescript, syntax-error

I am trying to annotate my variables with types but when running the code it simply gives off an error:

```js
let foo: number = 23;
console.log( foo );

// let foo: number = 23;
          ^

// SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
// [90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)[39m
// [90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)[39m
// [90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)[39m
// [90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)[39m
// [90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)[39m
// [90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)[39m
// [90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] // (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)[39m
// [90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47[39m
```

Comment: Is it a JS file or a TS?

Comment: @NirAlfasi Typescript

Comment: Add information about how you are running the code - what command are you using to execute the code?

Comment: I simply run it with 'node file.ts'

Comment: NodeJs currently *do not* support TS files execution directly, so you need to compile TS to JS first, or run scripts via `ts-node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

First compile it to plain JS with `tsc myfile.ts` and run the JS file with `node myfile.js`.

Or `npm install ts-node` which lets you run TS files like you would run JS files: `ts-node myfile.ts`